# Reset view after UIRotationGesture

Tags: xamarin.ios, uigesturerecognizer, cgaffinetransform

I have a UIRotationRecognizer on an UIImageView. After I rotate the view I would like to commit the changes so that next time I rotate the image it rotates naturally. Currently, with the code below, it looks like the origin is off after release the touch and try to rotate again.

```
    [Export("RotationSelector")]
    private void RotationSelector(UIRotationGestureRecognizer recognizer)
    {
        recognizer.View.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeRotation(recognizer.Rotation);

        if (recognizer.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
            // Reset origin here... 

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset your transformation like this:

```
recognizer.View.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity();
```

Comment: When I use CGAffineTransform.MakeIdentity() it returns its rotation to it's original state. I would like to keep the rotation that the user made. Should I set that angle of rotation separately?

Comment: I solved my problem came from not storing the values for later, and my confusion between the Apple CGAffineTransformation functions and the monotouch ones.