# how to set a rotated image as the image of a UIImageView after triggering UIRotationGesture?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition, image-rotation

I am creating an app, in which users can rotate an imageView on the screen, which will be saved as a UIImage for the next phase programatically. I have implemented all the required methods for rotating, which is done through UIRotationGesture, and everything works fine. The problem I have is that the rotation is not recorded for the image when I go to the next phase, and show the image in another view. I tried to add the gestureRecognizer to the UIImage of imageView, but I realised I can't do so. I also had a look at the [Reset view after UIRotationGesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021789/reset-view-after-uirotationgesture) thread, and I think I'm having this problem because I haven't stored something, but as I'm new, I don't know what and how. 
here's the code I used to rotate:

```
-(void)handleRotation:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotationGestureRecognizer
{

    if([rotationGestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    lastRotation = 0.0;
    return;
}

CGFloat rotation = 0.0 - (lastRotation - [rotationGestureRecognizer rotation]);

CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [rotationGestureRecognizer view].transform;
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform,rotation);

[[rotationGestureRecognizer view] setTransform:newTransform];

lastRotation = [rotationGestureRecognizer rotation];
}
```

I'd appreciate it if anyone could shed a light on my problem.

Thanks a lot